# Can't access Cognito Identity in API Gateway to use as a path parameter

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a `PUT` endpoint in `API Gateway` that puts an uploaded file directly into an `S3` bucket.

The `Method Request` requires authorisation from my `Cognito` authorisation pool and works fine.

I want to save the uploaded file with the users Cognito User ID as the filename.

I've tried creating a `URL Path Parameter` using `context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` but it's always blank. I've also tried getting access to `context.identity.user` which is also blank. If I create a path parameter for `context.requestId` this works fine and I can use it in the `Path override`.

I've also tried setting a `HTTP Header` as `X-Cognito-Id=context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` then accessing `method.request.header.X-Cognito-Id` in the `Path Parameters` section, but again it's still blank.

Here's a screenshot of my current setup trying multiple things. This results in a filename that has the `rid` and `wishid` but nothing else.

[image]

My other endpoints that use Lambda functions can access the Cognito user just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is: `context.authorizer.claims[cognito:username]` or possibly `context.authorizer.claims.email` depending on how you set up Cognito.

To see a list of all available properties you can temporarily add this to your mapping template: `$context.authorizer.claims.keySet()`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get what I needed from `context.authorizer.claims.sub`